# WPF/MVVM - WrapPanel in ItemsControl, Animation on added child

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, storyboard, transition

Given:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />              
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Where the "Controls binding" is an ObservableCollection in the viewmodel containing some sort of usercontrols.

As the content in the wrappanel is centered, the current behavior is as follows:

- UC A is added to the list, and displayed in the center of the panel.
- UC B is added to the list, UC A is moved to the left and UC B is added to the panel.
- UC C is added to the list, UC A and B
  is moved to the left and UC C is added to the panel.

What I want is to add a "movement" translation/transition when a new usercontrol is added, i.e. I want to show animate the transition of A/B..n the left as each UC is added.

I would prefer to do as much as possible in XAML, and not break the MVVM pattern.

[image]

*Bonus, I want to be able animate when an UC is removed too.*

Answer (score 1):

I consider Controls as an ObservableCollection of FrameworkElement
You can use this code:

```
<Window x:Class="Marathonbet.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" >
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="5"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" >
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="55"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" >
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnloaded1" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="55"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}" x:Name="x">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="15,2,15,2" Click="btAdd_OnClick"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Remove" Margin="64,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="15,2,15,2" Click="btRemove_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
public class MyObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>
    {

        private Storyboard unloadedStoryboard;

        public Storyboard UnloadedSotryBoard
        {
            get { return unloadedStoryboard; }
            set
            {
                unloadedStoryboard = value;
                unloadedStoryboard.Completed += UnloadedStoryboardOnCompleted;
            }
        }

        public Storyboard LoadedSotryBoard { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (FrameworkElement item in e.NewItems)
                    item.BeginStoryboard(LoadedSotryBoard);
            }
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        private HashSet<int> indexesToRemove = new HashSet<int>();

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            indexesToRemove.Add(index);
            var item = Items[index];
            UnloadedSotryBoard.Begin(item);
        }

        private void UnloadedStoryboardOnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            foreach (var i in new HashSet<int>(indexesToRemove))
            {
                base.RemoveItem(i);
                indexesToRemove.Remove(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public partial class MainWindow
    {

        public MyObservableCollection Controls { get; set; }


        #region Constructors

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Controls = new MyObservableCollection();
            InitializeComponent();
            Controls.LoadedSotryBoard = (Storyboard) FindResource("OnLoaded1");
            Controls.UnloadedSotryBoard = (Storyboard) FindResource("OnUnloaded1");
        }

        #endregion


        #region Events

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Controls.Add(new MyControl {DataContext = "A"});
            Controls.Add(new MyControl {DataContext = "B"});
            Controls.Add(new MyControl {DataContext = "C"});
        }

        private void btAdd_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Controls.Add(new MyControl {DataContext = (char) new Random().Next(0, Byte.MaxValue)});
        }

        private void btRemove_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Controls.Count == 0)
                return;
            Controls.RemoveAt(Controls.Count - 1);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```